# Non resident taxation: Received 1099-B

Tags: united-states, non-resident, form-1040

I am a US non-resident for tax purposes for FY 2023 (wasn't in the US for any day in the year). I had a brokerage account in the US as well from which I received 1099-B/1099-DIV/1099-INT/1042-S for my activity through the year. This happened even though I had submitted a W8-BEN to the brokerage (I guess it took some time for them to reflect the status correctly or perhaps I updated them with the w8-ben a bit later). How should I proceed?

Here's my understanding:

- Any income in 1099-INT which is portfolio interest income (e.g. ibonds, saving accounts) is not taxable for non-residents and can be ignored while filing tax returns.
- Form 1042-S should be attached with the return.
- Capital gains are not taxable for non-residents and 1099-B can be ignored while filing the return.
- 1099-DIV seems to only include dividends from early part of the year. I suspect tax on these dividends was not withheld, and this income should be included in schedule NEC (1040 nr).

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you got *both* 1042-S *and* the set of 1099s it is probably because the brokerage split periods to resident/non-resident treatment based on when the W8-BEN was received.

Assuming you're not a US citizen/green card holder or a US tax resident by some other statutory rule - you're correct. Capital gains are taxed by your country of residency, unless the property is physically located in the US (e.g.: real estate). Interest is also only taxed by your country of residency. The US does tax dividends paid by US corporations, so from your 1099-DIV you'll need to determine which ones apply (probably all), and report them on your 1040-NR. Since the 1042-S only covers part of your dividend income - you may end up owing additional taxes.